# Qt executeable crashes on another system

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2010, qtsql

Application is compiled using Qt 4.8.1 msvc10 and i have copied every .dll needed still the application crashes before starting and the module causing the crash is qtsql4.dll although it works fine within my system

how can i fix this error

Comment: Use dependency walker to find out which DLLs are missing on the other system if it is a DLL problem.

Comment: - Make sure MSVC runtime is installed - Make sure any QtSql plugins you use are shipped - Try disabling qtsql (if that's doable) just to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @Timo checked that issue and dependencies are fine by the looks of it

Comment: @Frank how can I find qtsqllite plugin couldn't find it with my qtsdk dir

Answer (score 0):

by copying sql drivers plugin directory along side the exe file found in Qt/mscvc10 the problem is solved